# SQL: How to use sum in group by

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  idteam,
        job,
        price,
        COUNT('X') as INFORMS,
        SUM(COUNT('X') * price) as TOTAL
FROM REP 
JOIN COSTS ON (job = categ AND to_number(to_char(REP,'YYYY')) = year)
GROUP BY idteam, job, price, TOTAL
ORDER BY IDTEAM;
```

I don't know why if I write TOTAL in GROUP BY and sql sends me error.. Identifier invalid.

I don't know how can I resolve that.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the sum in the group by list? That doesn't make sense as the sum is on the rows belonging to the group. Also why are you nesting aggregates? Show example source data and desired results.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some sample data and what you want to have as end result from that, because the query is having many issues...

Comment: And finally, what RDMS are you using as answers will tailor to needed SQL dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column "TOTAL" is an alias for SUM(COUNT('X') * price).
It cannot be used as a column identifier in the GROUP BY clause. You must say GROUP BY SUM(COUNT('X') * price), because "TOTAL" is unknown/not a column, at the time of grouping.
*After using GROUPING, you can refer to "TOTAL" in a  HAVING clause.*
In any case, the version/type of SQL your are using, doesn't allow it.

Additionally, why are you COUNTing 'X'? That X is a fixed value, and does not depend on any of your columns. If you would like to count each row, just use Count(1) or Count(*). Also, you don't need to SUM a COUNT. A COUNT is already summed.

You should post the structure of both REP and COSTS. Your linked image doesn't have enough info to support the query you wrote.

```
select
    idteam,
    -- job, /* not selected since it would need to be grouped*/
    sum(price) as 'theSUM'
from REP
join COSTS
    on REP.categ = COSTS.job
    and COSTS.year = 2016
group by idteam
order by idteam
```